# TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'

Tags: python, celery, urllib2, pyramid, urlopen

I'm using rest api to send push notifications.
Docs [are here.](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/)
I'm using pyramid and scheduling these push notifications using celery.

This is my code sample:

```
result = urllib2.urlopen(urlRequest, headers={
      "X-Parse-Application-Id": settings["parse.application.id"],
      "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": settings["parse.restapi.key"],
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })

connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()

connection.request('POST', '/1/push', json.dumps(data), )
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
```

But celery logs this error:

```
2015-08-18 16:39:45,092 INFO  [celery.worker.strategy][MainThread] Received task: app_v1_1.tasks.push_notification[877906d8-1ea7-4b1f-8a54-aa61bffb40e8]
2015-08-18 16:39:45,094 ERROR [celery.worker.job][MainThread] Task app_v1_1.tasks.push_notification[877906d8-1ea7-4b1f-8a54-aa61bffb40e8] raised unexpected: TypeError("urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/apnistreet/work/ve/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/comp/work/ve/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/comp/work/site/code/apnistreet_v1_1/tasks.py", line 168, in push_notification
    # "Content-Type": "application/json"
TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`urllib2.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) has no argument named `headers`:

> urllib2.urlopen: (url, data=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)
>
> Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a Request object.

Use [`urllib2.Request`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) to pass `headers`:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={
      "X-Parse-Application-Id": settings["parse.application.id"],
      "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": settings["parse.restapi.key"],
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
result = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: bigOther : How'll I add the headers then? I tried `urllib2.Request`, but I'm getting the same error, saying that `urlopen` got an unexpected keyword argument.

Comment: if you use `Request`, pass it only to `urlopen` : `urllib2.urlopen(req)` .. it can't give you the same problem because you are using no keyword here.

Comment: Same error! `TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'`

Comment: did you use `result = urllib2.urlopen(req)` and saved? notice, there is no header keyword here

Comment: Yes, I did! Its weird, I know.

Comment: be sure you used `urllib2.Request` and not `urllib2.urlopen` to pass headers?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**

The method `urllib2.urlopen` has no `headers` argument. This is what is indicated by the error message

> TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'

**Solution**

The `connection.request` is the place where you define the `headers`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473627/3419103) for an example.

Comment: Your code worked too, but bigOTHER's answer was closer to my original code. Thank you so much for the link, it was informative!